# Can I have several New methods in a rails controller on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application has several ways to create notifications:

- A user can create a notification using the standard "new" method
- A link in a view can create a notification from an action using a dedicated  "new_action"
- etc.

So I created additional route and views for the new_action_notification_path:

```
  resources :notifications do
      member do
        get :new_action
      end
      collection do
        get :index_all
      end
  end
```

In the controller

```
  # GET /notifications/new_action
  def new_action

    @playground = Playground.find(current_playground)
    @notification = @playground.notifications.build( playground_id:     params[:playground_id], …
```

And in the view:

```
        <%= link_to t('Reject'), new_action_notification_path(
                                    playground_id: current_playground,
                                    description: t("#{this_object.class.name}#{'Rejected'}"),
```

But this does not behave as expected:
If I write **new_action_notification_path** in the view, as above, the generated URL looks like **/notification/729/new_action?code=QWSTZ** ...

If I write **new_notification_path** in the same place, the generated URL looks like **/notification/new?code=QWSTZ** ...

Why is it different, and how can I remove the notification id from the first URL?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your url's are different is because you have a nested route for the `new_action`.

```
resources :notifications do
  member do
    get :new_action
  end
end
```

With a nested route, you are going to get an id number between your resources. The `729` is the id you are passing in to the `link_to` helper. The other route helper, `new_notification_path`, is creating a new notification, so it doesn't need an id. If you look at your routes, with `rails routes` in your console or `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` in your browser, you'll see that the `new_action` needs an id.

```
new_action_notification_path  GET  /notifications/:id/new_action
new_notification_path         GET  /notifications
```

The `:id` part of the route is a placeholder for an id number (although it can be anything you pass in, really) to look up the resource before it. In this case, the id is use to look up the notification.